# TinyDB on MIT App Inventor won't save data between screens

Tags: screen, app-inventor, tinydb

I'm a teacher of a CS class at a high school, and I don't have a ton of programming background, but my students are running into this issue:

They want to make an app that keep a username and password in a TinyDB so they can log in between screens. Right now, this is what they have:
New User Screen
[image: New User Screen]
Login Screen
[image]
Note: here testbox1 is the username and textbox2 is the password
When we've tried to get the tags on the login screen, they're wiped out. Don't know why...

Comment: After you tagged username/ password please click button2 to check if they were saved to TinyDB.. In the below tutorial they tagged them directly in TinyDB for ease of use but then query dB when login in, may be try if it works this way.. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4IESxs_I0cI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a dynamic tag is problematic...

let me recommend you to use 2 tags, the first tag could be "username", just store the username in that tag and as second tag you might want to use "password"... store the password in that tag

then in the other screen first read the values of both tags

Generally my recommendation is to **Use different screens wisely**
Before starting to create another screen, first you should think about is it really necessary? See also [Building apps with many screens](http://ai2.appinventor.mit.edu/reference/other/manyscreens.html) and [SteveJG's post about advantages/disadvantages](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mitappinventortest/ka-LS7wmWxs/wRbs70x2BgAJ), because in only one screen you also can use vertical arrangements to simulate different screens, just set the arrangements to visible = true/false as needed...

Also you might want to **switch screens correctly** to avoid memory issues during runtime of the app, see here https://puravidaapps.com/manager.php

btw. the App Inventor support forum you can find here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/mitappinventortest